# How to persist tflearn model.load

Tags: tflearn

I am using tflearn and I am new to it. I created a model and saved it. I am also able to load that model. But still I have a question unanswered.

What does model.load exactly do and how to persist that in memory even after the script ends?

Answer (score 0):

model.load(model_file='path') will load pre-saved model from path.

Suppose if you save a model using `model.save('my_tf_model')` and that will save the built model as `my_tf_model.meta` `my_tf_model.index` `my_tf_model.data-NNNNN-of-NNNNN`

you would retrieve this model using `model.load('my_tf_model')` and then use it for prediction.